# Xubuntu live usb persistence - how to?

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, persistence

I'm using Xubuntu 13.04 from live usb.

I know that in order to be able to keep files/settings/etc after restart, USB live disk should be created with some storage reserved.
However since I got this USB from a friend who created installation, I don't know if he reserved any space, and so my questions are:

- How can I find out amount of space reserved (if any)?
- If no space is reserved, can I manually chose USB/HDD location to store my settings in order to be able to boot into them the next time I log on?

I'm currently running a very long session and it would help me if I could somehow be able to store my settings (firefox, apt-gets, xrandr screen conf. ... ) to not have to do it again after I reboot.

Thanks,

IR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your settings and files are not saved when you reboot, you do not have persistence enabled.

You can either make a new Flash drive. This may be easiest as there are graphical tools to do this for you ("install" the iso to the flash drive and enable persistence).

See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent#Live_USB_creator_.28GUI-based.29

Alternately you can manually enable persistence. You can do this either by making a file or partition named "casper-rw". I think making a file would be easiest.

First, mount the flash drive at say /mnt

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

then make a file, change the count to increase the size:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/casper-rw bs=1M count=128

mkfs.ext4 /mnt/casper-rw
```

Then reboot, at the boot screen add the work "persistent" to the boot options.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Using_a_Loopback_File for details.

Comment: Or `fallocate -l 128m /mnt/casper-rw` ([info](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/fallocate/)) followed by mkfs.ext4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for the info on manually enabling persistence, exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: You are most welcome. @ignis Thank you for the fallocate command

Comment: If you want to allocate only what you write into the file - starting with the minimum, and growing when something is written - then create a sparse file, via dd or truncate: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844)