# Retrieve files from Ubuntu live usb

Tags: files, live-usb, data-recovery

I am new to ubuntu and I would like to ask how could I retrieve files that saved on my ubuntu live usb. In other words, when I was working on ubuntu live usb I download files pdf, zip, etc, am asking how can I retrieve these files to access them on my windows machine.

Thanks A lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xubuntu live usb persistence - how to?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321302/xubuntu-live-usb-persistence-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a Live CD on your USB drive, and giving it persistence.  Depending on how man GBs the USB drive is, you will have plenty of space to store items.  If you are in need of transferring them immediately, your best bet is likely to simply plug another USB drive into the system, and copy everything into it.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether you had created a persistence partition.

If you did not create persistence when you created the LiveUSB, and you aren't booted into the LiveUSB the files are likely gone as the Live session doesn't save files after you close out the session unless you create a persistence system.

If you did create persistence, you can boot up the LiveUSB and then open the partition that has Windows from within that Live session, and copy your files to the Windows partition so they're available when you boot into windows.