# using Ubuntu without installation

Tags: 14.04

I was using Ubuntu in pen drive without installing it. I installed some softawares in Ubuntu. After shutdown I tried using Ubuntu without installing it.  Everything all the work which I have done is gone. Is there anyway to keep all the data like installed softwares, downloaded files in pen drive. Use again like that..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xubuntu live usb persistence - how to?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321302/xubuntu-live-usb-persistence-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You can enable Persistance.[Reffer here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence)

Comment: we can choose persistence size while inastalling ubuntu in pendrive only