# Is it possible to install Ubuntu in a USB device?

Tags: system-installation, usb

Is it possible to install Ubuntu in a USB device? Don't want a live version, I want to install it like it was in a partition, install programs and save files. If so, how can I do it? I haven't found anything that makes me feel comfortable. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can just point the installer to your usb drive and it should work. Exactly the same as a normal install.

Notice that you can also create a live usb with persistence that can be used as an installer and to store your files and install packages.

Comment: If I don't misunderstand, can I use LiveUsb with the posibility to save files and packages like if it was installed in a laptop?

Comment: Correct, you can. Either create a file(using `dd`) named `casper-rw` on the root of your usb drive and format it as a device, with `mkfs.ext4 casper-rw` or create a partition on your usb drive and label it casper-rw, then format it with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdXX`. You can find more detailed instructions on: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence and http://askubuntu.com/questions/321302/xubuntu-live-usb-persistence-how-to

Comment: Ok, I just had a new question. Is it possible to "make a copy" of the system I have installed in my computer in a USB? Like install Ubuntu from Ubuntu in my computer. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it is a **lot** harder to do, and generally not worth the effort. It's faster and easier to copy just the files you care about to a new ubuntu install.

Comment: @Fcrtes https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall